# Passing data from one view to another

Tags: swift, parse-platform, mkmapview, mkpointannotation

I'm trying to get data about a point annotation in a map view to display in another view whenever I click on the annotation's callout accessory. My problem is that I have no idea how to tell the new view which annotation was tapped because I have multiple of them. I am saving my data in Parse. Can anyone help?
Thanks

Comment: I would advise watching Stanford cs193p course in iTunes.one of the lecture has a very good explanation.

Comment: Do you know which lecture talks about it?

Comment: Check the last 5 lectures. 13,14,15,16,17. Has to be there.

Comment: Ok I'll check it out thanks!

Comment: Don't forget to vote up )

Comment: It's 14 and 15, just finished watching them myself!

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to look at it